# How to find where js includes in Joomla 3.0 when admin is logged-in at front

Tags: javascript, joomla, joomla3.0

In my website (built using Joomla 3.0), When administrator user logged in, below java-scripts are being loaded additionally in head section.

```
<script src="/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/media/jui/js/jquery-noconflict.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/media/jui/js/jquery-migrate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/media/system/js/caption.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/media/jui/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/media/system/js/frontediting.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

These javascripts are making confliction and lots of javascript code is not working. Can someone please tell me where these java-scripts are being added when administrator is logged in.

Comment: I would not suggest removing these as they are core files and imports. If you have conflicting file, then **they** are the ones that are the problem.

Answer (score 1):

They are set in the layouts/joomla/edit/frontediting_modules.php

These are all necessary for front-end editing to work, and if you want to disable front-end editing altogether, you should do so via the admin (or a plug-in) and not by editing this core file.

Joomla can be a bit annoying in its mixing up JavaScript libraries (presumably as they move from Mootools to Bootstrap), but it should be possible to stop their scripts conflicting by updating your own, eg if using JQuery then it is safer to always use `jQuery` to reference it instead of `$`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this code to remove jquery. add the code above the include type head.

```
<?php

//Remove jquery
$search = array('jquery', 'jquery.min.js');
    // remove the js files
    foreach($this->_scripts as $key => $script) {
        foreach($search as $findme) {
            if(stristr($key, $findme) !== false) {
                unset($this->_scripts[$key]);
            }
        }
    }


?>

<jdoc:include type="head" />
```